# Changing the visibility of sliders in JSXGraph

Tags: javascript, slider, visibility, setattribute, jsxgraph

I'm using JSXGraph to create a bunch of sliders, whose visibility is supposed to be changed by a checkbox. Unfortunately, `setAttribute()` does not really work. It only changes the visibility of the "head" of the slider, but not of its range. Here is an example of my code in javascript:

```
ctx.slider_A = ctx.box_left.create("slider", [[50, 50], [230, 50], [0, 0.4, 1]], 
                {withLabel: false, snapWidth: 0.05, fillColor: ctx.textColor, visible: false});

function sliderVisibility(){
    var Checkbox = getElementById("check");
    if (Checkbox.checked == true) {
         ctx.slider_A.setAttribute({visible: true});
    }else{
         ctx.slider_A.setAttribute({visible: false});
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the problem? I'd be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself, even though the JSXGraph-documentation (https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/symbols/Slider.html) did not really help me. I made the mistake of assuming that a slider was treated as a single object, but it actually consists of four parts: the slider itself (the thing that I previously referred to as "head"), the baseline, the highline, and the ticks of the baseline. If you want to change the visibility of the whole thing, you need to change it for each component.

I don't know whether there is a more elegant way to do this (I'm pretty sure there is, but for me this solution is sufficient), but here's how I did it:

```
function sliderVisibility(){
    var Checkbox = getElementById("check");
    if (Checkbox.checked == true) {
         ctx.slider_A.setAttribute({visible: true});
         ctx.slider_A.baseline.setAttribute({visible:true});
         ctx.slider_A.highline.setAttribute({visible:true});
         ctx.slider_A.ticks.setAttribute({visible:true});
    }else{
         ctx.slider_A.setAttribute({visible: false});
         ctx.slider_A.baseline.setAttribute({visible:false});
         ctx.slider_A.highline.setAttribute({visible:false});
         ctx.slider_A.ticks.setAttribute({visible:false});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution (which works at least with v1.00+):

```
    var s1 = board.create('slider', [[-3,1], [2,1],[-10,1,10]], {
            name: 'A',
            visible: true,
            baseline: {visible: 'inherit'},
            highline: {visible: 'inherit'},
            label: {visible: 'inherit'}
        });
```

Then, toggling should be possible with

```
    s1.setAttribute({visible: false});
```